# Swift, Modal Segue and ViewController Issue

Tags: xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

I have two ViewControllers, StartVC and MainVC. When app starts, I use a Modal Segue to move from StartVC to MainVC.

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("StartToMain", sender: self)
```

MainVC then shows a Map, loads user location shows it on map and zooms into it and creates some annotations on it and displays a AdMob banner. All works well.

Then when user taps a back button, the segue is dismissed using:

```
self.presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Now when user taps a button and the modal segue is fired again and users gets to MainVC again, the map is still showing user location but does not zoom in, does not load any annotations, does not set region and admob banner is not loaded.

I am baffled by this. I have already checked that the ViewDidLoad and ViewDidAppear for MainVC are firing the second time too and the code execution even reaches the functions which are supposed to zoom into map etc but it does not take effect. Does anyone has any idea, what could be causing this?

I should also mention that the second time user gets to MainVC, below error is thrown by AdMob trying to display an interstitial ad:

> Warning: Attempt to present < GADInterstitialViewController:
>   0x139b07e20> on < myApp.MainVC: 0x135672f20> whose view is not in the
>   window hierarchy!

Additionally, currently, the function call to do all the missing functionality is inside the `locationManager didUpdateLocations` method. If I move it out to for example, `viewDidAppear`, it works.

Comment: Are you using a Navigation Controller to do this? Or is it just one view controller and another? And are you presenting modally or using push?

Comment: I am not using navigation and I am presenting modally because I like the horizontal flip effect.

Comment: Hrm... You might try embedding in a Nav controller just to see if things behave more appropriately. My guess is it has something to do with the reference to `presentingViewController` which has been unreliable at best for me.

Answer (score 0):

Some things you can try.

First: Make sure you are doing all navigation in the viewDidAppear method. You should not call another VC in ViewDidLoad or ViewWillAppear methods.

Second: You can use a unwind segue for navigate back to the StartVC. Create the unwind segue at the storyboard and then call it programmatically like this:

`self.performSegueWithIdentifier("UnwindSegue", sender: self)`

[You can find more info about unwind segues here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2298/_index.html)

Hope it helps.